# TTTAttributedLabel not displaying the last line when having Emoji symbols

Tags: ios, uilabel

We are using "TTTAttributedLabel" for displaying labels. For calculating the correct rectangle size, we use NSString's "sizeWithFont" method, with a "constrainedToSize" the width of the field.
The calculation is fine, unless there are some Emoji symbols in the text, and the text is multi line (for example: smiley-newLine-smiley). In that case, the returned size is too small (vertically), and the last line is not shown. If the text does not contain any Emoji (e.g. X-newLine-X) - the size is correct.
Our font is "HelveticaNeue" size:16.25, in case is makes any difference.
Is there a better way to calculate the needed size, so that it will work with Emoji as well?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a same situation when making auto-height label according to the contents of the label.
Everything seems fine, except when there are emojis in label content.

It was because I did't use the correct setText method for AttributedString.

```
[label setText:text afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ 
    return mutableAttributedString;
}];
```

This is the correct way to set AttributedString, but what I did is

```
[label setAttributedText:text];
```

So it was getting wrong label heights when it includes emojis in it.

I solved this problem by changing this set method with the correct one as described in Github manual.